# Graphing an equation in cylindrical coordinates with gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a cylinder of radius = 1. I need to plot the function f(theta,z)=exp(theta-0.2*z) where theta is the azimuthal angle and z is along the height of the cylinder, how would this be plotted in gnuplot ? I would like to see the cylinder as well.

Comment: Does your function f(theta, z) give the radial coordinate? Otherwise you have a 4D problem at hand, which is very complicated from the visualization point of view.

Comment: Yes it gives the radial co-ordinate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your function f(theta, z) gives the radial coordinate, this can be done in parametric mode, where variables `u` and `v` are assigned to `theta` and `z`, respectively:

```
set parametric

set urange [0:2*pi]
set vrange [-1:1]

f(u,v)=exp(u-0.2*v)

set xrange [-2:2]
set yrange [-2:2]
set zrange [-2:2]

set isosamples 100,10

splot cos(u),sin(u),v title "cylinder", \
0.01*cos(u)*f(u,v),0.01*sin(u)*f(u,v),v title "function (scaled down)"
```

[image]

Note I have down scaled your function (0.01*f instead of f) since it would be too large compared with the size of the cylinder otherwise.

`set parametric` uses a triplet of coordinates (x,y,z) where each is given in terms of the independent variables `u` and `v`. In your case (cylindrical coordinates) u = theta and so x = r cos(u) and y = r sin(u); v = z. Since your function f (or 0.01*f) gives the radial coordinate, x = f * cos(u) and y = f * sin(u).